# Querybuilder : Error: Expected end of string, got '('

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

This is the query :

```
public function getTeachersBySchool(School $school)
    {  

        $qb2 = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder('UserGroup ug')
                ->select('ug.members')
                ->where('ug.school = :school')
                ->andWhere('ug.name = "teachers"')
                ->setParameter('school', $school)    
                ;

        $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder('Project\UserBundle\Entity\User u');

        $query = $qb
                ->select('Project\UserBundle\Entity\User')
                ->where($qb->expr()->in('Project\UserBundle\Entity\User', $qb2->getDQL()))   
            ;

        return $query;
    }
```

I can't understand why I got this error, especially that the SQL query that is made seems correct :

```
SELECT Project\UserBundle\Entity\User WHERE Project\UserBundle\Entity\User IN(SELECT ug.members WHERE ug.school = :school AND ug.name = "teachers")
```

EDIT : I don't think that the problem is coming from the `andWhere('ug.name = "teachers"')` because even when deleting this line the error stills the same.

Comment: try  `->andWhere("ug.name = teachers")`

Comment: same problem :/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    $qb2 = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder('UserGroup ug')
            ->select('ug.members')
            ->where('ug.name = teachers')
            ->andWhere('ug.school = :school')
            ->setParameter('school', $school)    
            ;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
        $qb2 = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder('UserGroup ug')
            ->select('ug.members')
            ->where('ug.school = :school')
            ->andWhere('ug.name = :teachers')
            ->setParameters([
               'school' => $school,
               'teachers' => "teachers"
            ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    $qb2 = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('ug.members')
            ->from(UserGroup::class, 'ug')
            ->where('ug.school = :school')
            ->andWhere('ug.name = "teachers"')
            ->setParameter('school', $school);
```